# How to Launch python EXE from URL and Pass Information Through the URL

Tags: python, powerbi, exe

I have a python script that I have converted into a attributable executable. This script uses selenium to look up a part number on my company website. My end goal is to integrate this into Power Bi so that any part number in a Power Bi list can be easily looked up. My idea is to make a URL that can be a clickable link in Power Bi. This URL would call the executable from a network drive as well as pass the part number to the script. To incorporate the part number I would like to add it onto the end of the URL and have the script pick it up from there.

Is this just a dream or can a relatively new programmer do this? I have found a way to make a web-page that contains a python script, but not one that I can pass information to without user interaction. Is there a tool out there that will allow me to click a URL that launches a local .exe and passes information to it while running in the background?

Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple flask app that has a `GET` view and pass information to it with `GET` or `POST` parameters, in the view you would then execute whatever you want.